# access variable in template from views.py - Django

Tags: python, django

This is my first time messing with django and I am having trouble passing variables from a view function to a template html file.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    try:
        ms_identity_web.acquire_token_silently()
        authZ = f'Bearer {ms_identity_web.id_data._access_token}'
        graph_user_picture = requests.get(settings.USERPHOTO,
                                      headers={"Authorization": authZ})
        file = open("Sample/static/user_iamge"+str(ms_identity_web.id_data.username).split(" ")[0]+".png", "wb")
        file.write(graph_user_picture.content)
        file.close()

        clamdata = context_processors.context(request)
        print(clamdata["claims_to_display"]["preferred_username"])
        userdata = requests.get(settings.ENDPOINT+"/"+clamdata["claims_to_display"]["preferred_username"],
                                    headers={"Authorization": authZ}).json()
        print(userdata)
        return render(request, "flow/index.html", userdata)
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)
        return render(request, "flow/start.html")
```

and I am trying to send `userdata` over to index.html like so:

```
<div class="ms-Persona-details">
        <div class="ms-Persona-primaryText">{{ userdata["displayName"] }}</div>
        <div class="ms-Persona-secondaryText">{{ userdata["jobTitle"] }}</div>
        <div class="ms-Persona-tertiaryText">{{ userdata["businessPhones"][0] }}</div>
        <div class="ms-Persona-tertiaryText">{{ userdata["userPrincipalName"] }}</div>
      </div>
```

However, I am getting either no variables showing up on the screen or I get an error like this:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '["displayName"]' from 'userdata["displayName"]'
```

I assume I am missing something basic in index.html to pass variables from the views.py to the index.html file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not how django template works, DTL (django template language) has some rules.

try this

```
 # views
 return render(request, "flow/index.html",  {'userdata':userdata})
 # template
<div class="ms-Persona-primaryText">{{ userdata.displayName }}</div>
```

refer this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

Comment: I didn't know you <b>HAD</b> to use dot notation. Also the real trick was setting the return variable as a dict in the return template `{'userdata':userdata}`. I will give you the answer once Stackoverflow allows me to (For some reason I have to wait 6 minutes before I can declare this the answer)